# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder in Myeclipse

Tags: hibernate, struts2, jboss, liferay

I am running an application developed using Struts2,Hibernate in MyEclipse. when i am deploying the application in liferay-portal on JBoss server, it is giving following exception in Life-Ray portal:-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:189)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:112)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:105)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:235)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:208)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:221)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:151)
    com.allied.util.HibernateSessionFactory.<clinit>(HibernateSessionFactory.java:12)
```

i have added following jars in WEB-INF\lib path:- log4j-1.2.14.jar,slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar.

i am writing this line for connection of database in DAOImpl class => session=HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(); but this line is not executing. I dont know what is the exact problem.

Please help me out..

Hibernate Struts2 jboss liferay hibernate-session

Comment: please, put the code of the initialization of your java class

Comment: thanks mark for quick reply...but i am not getting u exactly..where is the  code of the initialization of java class

Comment: have you try to remove the jar-files.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that the initialization of Hibernate not working because that will be done from another class loader, like liferay self (ROOT).

You can try to move "log4j-1.2.14.jar,slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar" from portlet to ~/tomcat/lib or ~/tomcat/lib/ext

By this solution it is better to remove this JARs from ~/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/lib/* too.

Comment: Actually Mark iam running my application on JBoss server...i think you are telling to remove jar from tomcat folder

Comment: JBoss has same structure like tomcat. Put this libraries to common class loader: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/class-loader-howto.html